# RSpec combine block matcher with non-block matcher

Tags: ruby, rspec

I would like to check if my class is creating a new object and returning an instance of it. My idea was to combine `change` matcher with `be_instance_of` matcher but RSpec doesn't allow to do it.

```
expect { subject.call }.to change { Model.count }.by(1).and be_an_instance_of(Model)
```

I don't want to split it into two different `expects` with one without the block to avoid multiple invocations of the same method.

What is the general approach to this kind of situations? How should I handle my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `subject` as `subject.call` and do this:

```
specify do
  expect { subject }.to change { Model.count }.by(1)
  expect(subject).to be_an_instance_of(Model)
end
```

So if previously your subject was

```
subject { Foo.new }
```

make it

```
subject { Foo.new.call }
```

`let` and `subject` calls **are memoized**, so it'll be only called once.

There is only one problem: if the first expectation fails - the second will not run (and this is SomethingToAvoidInSpecs™) so consider [aggregating failures](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/aggregating-failures) to remedy it.

Comment: ...Or just make it two tests, not one. If `subject` is not an expensive (slow) operation, then this is the normal practice.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't thought about putting it into the subject. Spent over an hour trying to solve it by the different way but it was so simple...

Comment: @TomLord of course one can do that, but from the question I got the impression that he want's to avoid it.

Comment: @meta I consider this to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  They are providing an attempted solution, *not* the original problem. Your answer is valid and interesting, but I think it's also worth pointing out the "simpler"  option too!